# In Xcode, I can upload my Swift application using firebase, but I cannot import data from firestore into my application. What is the solution?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to make a picture display application. I'm new to xcode. When I upload the picture, my data is sent to the cloud firestore. But when I want to take it to my Feed screen, I cannot see the data. It says "Configuration not found. Using default configuration" in the sub-tab. I installed and updated it again and again by doing pod install. I installed xcode 11.7 and I can't see my data.

feedViewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    var userEmailArray = [String]()
    var userCommentArray = [String]()
    var likeArray = [Int]()
    var userImageArray = [String]()
    var documentIdArray = [String]()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    
     getDataFromFirestore()
    }
    
  func getDataFromFirestore() {
        
        
   let fireStoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
        
        /*    let settings = fireStoreDatabase.settings
        
        settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
        fireStoreDatabase.settings =  settings
        
        */
    
      
        fireStoreDatabase.collection("Posts").order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener {(snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print (error?.localizedDescription as Any)
           }else {
                if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil{
                    
                
                    self.userImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.userEmailArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.likeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.documentIdArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                 
                    
             
                for document in snapshot!.documents{
                let documentID = document.documentID
              self.documentIdArray.append(documentID)
                    
                    if let postedBy = document.get("postedby") as? String{
                        self.userEmailArray.append(postedBy)
                        
                        
                    }
                    if let postComment = document.get("postComment") as? String{
                        self.userCommentArray.append(postComment)
                        
                        
                    }
                    if let likes = document.get("likes") as? Int{
                        self.likeArray.append(likes)
                        
                        
                    }
                    if let imageUrl = document.get("imageUrl") as? String{
                        self.userImageArray.append(imageUrl)
                    }
                        
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
          }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userEmailArray.count
        }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        cell.userEmailLabel.text = userEmailArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.likeLabel.text = String(likeArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.commentLabel.text = userCommentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userImageView .sd_setImage(with: URL (string: self.userImageArray[indexPath.row]))
        cell.documentIdLabel.text = documentIdArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

feedCell

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var documentIdLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       
    }

    @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let fireStoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
        
        if let likeCount = Int(likeLabel.text!) {
            let likeStore = ["likes" : likeCount + 1 ] as [String : Any]
        
            fireStoreDatabase.collection("Posts").document(documentIdLabel.text!).setData(likeStore, merge: true)
        }
    }
}
```

UploadVievController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
  
    @IBOutlet weak var commentText: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chooseImage))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        
    }
    
    @objc func chooseImage() {
        
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func makeAlert(titleInput: String, messageInput: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    

    @IBAction func actionButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReference = storage.reference()
        
        let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("media")
        
        
        if let data = imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
            
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            
            let imageReference = mediaFolder.child("\(uuid).jpg")
            imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                } else {
                    
                    imageReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        
                        if error == nil {
                            
                            let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString
                            
                            
                            //DATABASE
                            
                           let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
                            
                           var firestoreReference : DocumentReference? = nil
                            
                           let firestorePost = ["imageUrl" : imageUrl!, "postedBy" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.email!, "postCommend" : self.commentText.text!,"date" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), "likes" : 0 ] as [String : Any]

                          firestoreReference = firestoreDatabase.collection("Posts").addDocument(data: firestorePost, completion: { (error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    
                                    self.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                                    
                                } else {
                                    
                                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "asd.jpg")
                                    self.commentText.text = ""
                                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                                }
                            })
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's entirely too much code for us to parse through and you need to do troubleshooting before posting. We need to know if this issue is related to Firebase or something else. First step is to determine if any Firebase  data is actually loaded. Add a line immediately following `fireStoreDatabase.collection("Posts")` of `print(snapshot)` and see if anything prints. If it does, move the print statement farther down inside the closure, say inside the for loop `for document in snapshot!.documents` add `print(document)'. Keep doing that until you know if your firebase data has loaded correctly.

Comment: To discard any issue related with a Firebase rule try to run your application by running your Firestore instance in test mode (disable authentication on firestore via [firebase rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics))

Comment: @JAHernadez I did what it said All authenticated users I opened access but there was no change and no errors xcode

Comment: Can you try to follow the [Firebase/Firestore quickstart](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-ios/firestore/readme/)? only to verify the connectivity to firestore and compare the code, maybe something in your code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue related to the constraints of your cell. Try to set a fixed size for your table view cells.

Comment: i updated the cells but it always gives this error "[Firebase / Analytics] [I-ACS023130] Configuration not found. Using default configuration
"

Comment: Did you check that userEmailArray is not empty? Firebase Analytics has nothing to do with your error. I would suggest you check the size of your array after getting the response of Firebase.